# Java rectangle of stars with for loop with separate print as String

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops

I need to get a rectangle made of `*` of size 5x4.

I need to provide implementation for this code

```
String[] number1 =model1(5,4);
print(model1);
```

Here is my attempt:

```
public class mm {
    public static void main(String args[]) {    
        String[] number1 = model1(5, 4);
        print(model1);
    }

    private static String[] model1(int i, int j) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int width=i;
        int height=j;

        for ( int row = 0 ; row < height ; row++ )
        {
            for ( int col = 0 ; col < width ; col++ )
            {
                System.out.print("*")
            }
            System.out.print(" ")
        }
        String[] a = a.new().amodel1(i,j);
        return a ;
    }

    public static void print(String[] n) {
        System.out.println(n);
    }

    public static void print(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: your print method is wrong for printing an array, you should probably loop through its contents and print each element in the array instead of printing the array object

Comment: Or use `Arrays.toString()`. Also, you are printing from a method that is clearly supposed to modify a `String[]`, not print its output.

Comment: @Natecat This will not print data in form `***` but `[*, *, *]` which doesn't look like what OP needs.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Offtopic ... I have something in my mind ... there was a question about finding duplicates in arrays of arrays; and I thought you responded to that with a nice solution using xor. Was that really you, if so, can you drop a link to that answer?

Comment: @GhostCat [Yes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41203034/2970947). But, algorithm was flawed. `0,0,6` was evaluating the same as `0, 2, 4`.

Comment: What is `String[] a = a.new().amodel1(i,j);` supposed to do? What programming language is this? You’ve tagged your question with `[java]`, but this isn’t anywhere close to Java.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach was fine but if you need a 1D array, then your approach won't do what you want.

You forgot to add the elements to the array then pass that array to the `print` method, take a look at this code:

This adds the `*` character to the array and if it's on the width end, then it adds a line break escape sentence (`\n`), then simply print the array

```
public class StarsRectangleExample {

    public static String[] drawStars(int width, int height) {
        String[] array = new String[height * width];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = "*";
            if ((i + 1) % width == 0) {
                array[i] += "\n";
            }
        }
        return array;
    }

    public static void print(String[] stars) {
        for (int i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(stars[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] stars = drawStars(5, 4);
        print(stars);
    }
}
```